# Async map not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have something like this

```
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');//request urls

var urls = ['url1','url2', 'url3' ];

function requestUrl( url, callback){
  console.log(callback.toString());
  request(url, function(err, resp, body){
    callback(null, body)
  })
}

function cb(err, results){ console.log(results); }
```

then I call it via

```
async.map(urls, requestUrl, cb);
```

My 'cb' never gets called. I am printing out the 'callback' using  .toString() method function in the second parameter and it looks like this.

```
function (err, v) {
  results[index] = v;
  callback(err);
}
```

Why is it ignoring my callback and putting it in its own?

Comment: You should not forget to pass on `err` to `callback`. It's not always `null`.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `request` does call the callbacks you pass to it?

Comment: `callback` is not supposed to be the same as `cb`. `callback`'s purpose is to accumulate the output values of your function and then check that an error did not occur or if all asynchronous calls are complete.

Comment: The request for my urls is executing and I am getting the data I need. However I cannot pass it to my defined callback.  Their callback seems to be aggregating the results but its not calling my callback 'cb' so I can get the information.

Comment: Hi Chris, what do you mean by 'callback' isnt the same? And if 'callback' is not the same as 'cb' then how am I supposed to get and use all the results?

Comment: I understand their callback which is printing is accumulating the results but that should affect my 'cb' callback which is not getting called at all

Comment: Ok, good. Your `cb` should be called when every call is complete or an error is encountered. You need to check that `request` is executing the callback function that you're passing to it for each url, as @Bergi states, and also alter your line `callback(null, body)` to be `callback(err, body)` or `if (err) { callback(err); } else { callback(null, body); }`.

Comment: Yea structurally its the same as I am passing null instead of error and even after this change its still not working.  Back at square 1

Answer (score 1):

### async.map(arr, iterator, [callback])

arr - An array to iterate over.

iterator(item, callback) -The iterator is passed a callback(err, transformed) which must be called once it has completed with an error (which can be null) and a transformed item.

callback(err, results) - Optional A callback which is called when all iterator functions have finished, or an error occurs. Results is an array of the transformed items from the arr.

Results is an array.

Take a look at this [runnable](http://code.runnable.com/VdZJKyUvLzx-Ygmc/async-test-for-node-js-and-hello-world).

```
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');

var urls = ['http://www.google.fr', 'http://twitter.fr'];

function requester(url, done) {
  console.log('request: %s', url);
  request(url, function(err, r, body) {
    console.log('request is done');
    console.log('have error on it ?', err !== null);
    if (err) return done(err);
    var res = res;
    var b = body;
    done(null, {
      response: r,
      body: b
    });
  })
}

async.map(urls, requester, function(err, r) {
  console.log('async callback');
  console.log('have error on it ?', err !== null);
  if (err){ 
    console.log('on error', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('it\'s a success! Now take a look at result :)');
  console.log('results[%s]', r.length);
});
```

If you call your own endpoint (like http://localhost:3000/your/endpoint) make sure this request don't crash your node app.

Answer (score 0):

This was my fault.  When you request data and that request fails async tends to fail silently along with it not returning your request.  If nothing seems to be returning from your requests I would say print out any and all errors and check if any conditions not being met.

For instance I had an

```
if

else if
```

which but neither was executing leaving it hanging and causing erratic behavior that was hard to pinpoint. 3 hour frustrating lesson in clean programming.